For AWS Elastic Redis Global Cache do we need to create again users and user group even in secondary region too again
I have created list of users and usergroups and associated it with the redis global datastore primary cluster (self designed Replication group Cluster), for accessing the secondary region do I need to create separate users and usergroup in that region too. Also are secondary region only read replicas or can we perform write operation too i.e are they enabled with write forwarding to the primary region's writer instance for performing write operations or are they just read replicas and so only get functions only can be performed on them
I need more clarification though I have read the documentation

In my experience using AWS Elasticache Redis, when you have a Redis global datastore with a primary cluster and a secondary region, here are some key points you need to note.

You only need to create users and usergroups in the primary cluster. These users and usergroups will be replicated automatically to the secondary region.

The secondary region is typically read-only. This means you can perform read operations (GET functions) on the secondary region.

Direct write operations (such as SET functions) are not possible on the secondary region. However, some setups allow for write forwarding, where write operations are forwarded from the secondary region to the primary region's writer instance. Check your specific Redis configuration and documentation to confirm if write forwarding is enabled.


In summary, you don't need to create users and usergroups again for the secondary region, and generally, the secondary region is used for read operations only. If write forwarding is enabled, you can perform write operations that will be redirected to the primary region.

Usersgroup - ACL are manged externally by Redis cache externally and independent of the cluster. the users and usergroup are specific to AWS Region- I think because they are replicated to other region

Correct me if I am wrong

Yes, you are correct. Redis ACLs and user groups are managed externally and are specific to each AWS region, so they are not automatically replicated across regions. You will need to create the same users and user groups separately in each region. There might be a better way, but this is how I’ve handled it in the past. Also, secondary regions are generally read-only, but with write forwarding enabled, write operations can be forwarded to the primary region’s writer instance.

when checking list of users and usergroup created on one region (let us say us-east-1) but cannot find them replicated them in the user management or user groups in other secondary region us-west-2; Is it they are created in one region and managed in one region only but in the second region the users may not be visible in user management tab of us-west-2 but they are having the necessary permissions to access the secondary cluster and if some write operation are executed then they are write-forwarded to the primary cluster
